# SQL Event through ODBC

Tags: sql, .net, odbc

I have an application connected to a SQL Server database through an ODBC connection.

Can SQL Server throw an event through the ODBC connection to the application to let the application know that a record has been added to a database table without the application having to query the table every few seconds for activity?

Comment: May be this can help....Refernce ....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103772/raise-an-event-from-mysql-and-handle-it-from-vb-net-or-something-similar

Comment: I took a look at that, but that is for MySQL.  I'm working with a SQL Server database.
I need some signalling construct from SQL through the ODBC connections to the application.
The alternative is for the application to be constantly querying the database tables for recent activity and that would be messy.